Error in Flutter new project just created with flutter create 'name'
I just create a new project in flutter with flutter create , but when I want to run the project I have errors.
'I have reinstalled the visual code, android studio, I create the emulator with all the downloads, but nothing ....
this is the code.'
 allprojects {
    repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
  }
}

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
   subprojects {
     project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
    subprojects {
       project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

And I have this error
Build file 'C:\Users\Dan\Flutter Projects\casa1\android\build.gradle' line: 13'

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Build completed with 1 failures.
> org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider


Ensure that you have the necessary dependencies declared in your build.gradle file.
  dependencies {
     implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bouncycastle:1.68'
  }


Yes thanks, I place that line of code, previously to make the question, in to build.gadle from /app but no success.
